# How to make the swipe left/right gestures more free?

Tags: java, android, swipe, ontouchlistener

I have this code. It works. I can swipe left and right and get the desired result. However, the problem is that I have to swipe almost strictly horizontally for the swipe action to work. I want more freedom when swiping. I want the swipe to also work when I swipe diagonally. How should I change this code?

here is the code

```
import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {  

        Context context = null;

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }



        private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                boolean result = false;
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                     if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY) - 50) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                onSwipeRight();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffY > 0) {
                                onSwipeBottom();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeTop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY) - 50)` condition determines if it's a horizontal or vertical swipe. First thing you can do is make that `50` density-dependent by multiplying it by `DisplayMetrics.density`.

If that doesn't produce the result you're looking for, consider using trigonometry to determine the angle between the start and end point. Consider the vector from `e1` to `e2` and find the angle between it and the `x` axis. It should be `arccos(diffX/sqrt(diffX*diffX + diffY*diffY))` (figuring out how to make it work in all 4 quadrants is left as an exercise for the reader).

By comparing that angle to a specific range of degrees (e.g. -45 to 45 for right swipe), you can achieve a much more intuitive and customizable result.

Note that this only considers direction and not velocity.